# Vue generate router link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have vue application for displaying videos. 
I want to automatic random generate router link every time when i click on

```
<router-link to="/video/this_value_to_be_random">Random video</router-link>
```

In component

```
<vue-video-background videoSrcMp4="path/to/your/video/file-this_value_to_be_random.mp4"></vue-video-background>
```

I want to pass this random value/number to **this_value_to_be_random**
Purpose for this is every time when i click to link i want to display different video in the same component. Or different video path. Random number between 1-5.

- path/to/your/video/file_v1.mp4
- path/to/your/video/file_v2.mp4
- path/to/your/video/file_v3.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method that generates a random link and bind it to `to` prop as follows :

```
  <router-link :to="randomLink()">Random video</router-link>
  ...

 methods:{
     randomLink(){
          let rnd=Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
          return 'path/to/your/video/file_v'+rnd+'.mp4'
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Js you can use :

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
```

This will give you a number between 1 and 10